# CSS background with image and gradient, how to write in multiple lines ?

Tags: css

I'd like to express the following CSS property definition broken out to each  individual properties.

This is the one-liner property definition which does work :

```
div{
  background: url('packages/select2/select2.png') no-repeat 100% -22px, linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 85%, #eee 99%) 0 0;
}
```

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
div{
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 85%, #eee 99%) 0 0;
    background-image: url('packages/select2/select2.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat 100% -22px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

Actually, it's not possible to layer things the way you want to by defining the individual properties. Since you're trying to position and repeat layers differently, the only way to do it is with a single-line `background` definition. Otherwise you'd just override previous property definitions with later ones. It would work if you had a single `background-position` property for all layers, but not otherwise.

Either use a single-line `background` definition with commas between the layers, or break the background into multiple elements and layer them in the DOM.

Comment: I tried your solution, but the background image is in the wrong position.

Comment: You're right, because what you want is impossible hehe. See my edit.

Comment: Turns out I don't need the linear-gradient,  so if I break out these properties it seems to work : `background-image: url('packages/select2/select2.png')
    background-repeat: no-repeat
    background-position: 100% -22px`

Comment: @looshi yep it's perfectly valid to define properties individually when you have a single layer.

Comment: Sure it's possible...just comma separate them.

Comment: @jcd What do you mean by 'layer' ?

Comment: Your original one-liner property definition has two layers, the image and the gradient.